# Javascript: DOM, appendChild - a couple of questions

Tags: javascript, dom, appendchild

I am just learning this stuff so please forgive if my code or questions are very basic.

My "working code" (no errors etc) just so you know what I have so far:

```
var t = document.createElement("table"),
    tr = document.createElement("tr"),
    tr2 = document.createElement("tr"),
    td = document.createElement("td"),
    td2 = document.createElement("td"),
    a = document.createElement("a"),
    strong = document.createElement("strong");

t.style.width = "80%";
t.style.border = "0";
t.cellspacing = "2";
t.cellpadding = "2";
```

.

```
for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    the_table_color = nodes[i].getAttribute("table_color");
    the_type = nodes[i].getAttribute("type");
    alt_link = nodes[i].getAttribute("alt_link");
    link_for_deletion = nodes[i].getAttribute("link_for_deletion");
    comment = nodes[i].getAttribute("comment");

    tr.bgColor = the_table_color;
    t.appendChild(tr);

    td.width = "16%";
    td.vAlign = "top";
    tr.appendChild(td);

    strong.appendChild(document.createTextNode(the_type));
    td.appendChild(strong);

    td.width = "16%";
    td.vAlign = "top";
    tr.appendChild(td);

    td2.width = "70%";
    td2.vAlign = "top";
    tr.appendChild(td2);

    a.href = alt_link;
    a.appendChild(document.createTextNode(alt_link));
    a.target = "_blank";
    td2.appendChild(a);
}
```

As you can see from above I have this bit:

```
td = document.createElement("td"),
    td2 = document.createElement("td"),
```

and the reason for that is, if I do not have the "td" declared again, the first one gets overwritten and the second one does not display...
A) Is that the right way of doing this? (not sure if this is the right approach,I came about the solution of declaring another variable to get it to work, but it seems like extra code)

Then this line of code:

```
strong.appendChild(document.createTextNode(the_type));
```

just adds all the stuff from the loop in there :(
For example of the first iteration of the for() loop has `abc` and the second had `def` it displays abcdef instead of abc the first time and def the second.
B) Why is that and how do I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: For starters, learn to properly indent your code. Editors like WebStorm (or even jsFiddle) have buttons for that...

Comment: All those variables at the top of the for-loop should be declared... you're polluting the global namespace.

Comment: Give the guy a break - he stated he was learning.

Comment: @Šime Vidas, what are you talking about? I declared all of them via a "var" keyword

Comment: @Ryan: You're correct, `var ... = ..., ... = ...` in fact uses `var` for both.

Comment: @pimvdb, @Ryan: The ones at the top of the `for` statement aren't declared (unless they are elsewhere in the code). That's what @Šime Vidas noted in his comment.

Comment: @Paul: What's the problem? Šime is giving good, helpful advice.

Comment: @patrick, yes they are, at the end of each declaration is a comma not a semi-colon.

Comment: @Ryan: We're talking about the ones in the `for` loop. There's no `var`, and even if there was, they're separated by `;`. `the_table_color=...; the_type=...; etc.`. Of course you may have them declared outside the for loop.

Comment: aha, when you said "at the top of the for" i thought you meant "top of" (as in "over"), my mistake, but yes, those are declared elsewhere, did not want to post too much code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your for loop is executing against the same instance with each iteration.  You will not get multiple rows of data unless you perform your:

```
document.createElement("TR");
document.createElement("TD");
```

within the loop body.  Otherwise, you're exactly right, you're just appending the same text to the same row and table cell each iteration through the loop.

It sounds like you need to change your approach to something like:

```
var table = document.createElement("TABLE");
for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++){
    var tr = document.createElement("TR");
    var td = document.createElement("TD");
    tr.appendChild(td);
    table.appendChild(tr);

    // do something to to td    
}
```

Let me know if I've misunderstood your question, but if you're wondering why your table is building only one row or repeatedly modifying the same cell, that's definitely why...  if there's more to your question let me know and I'll update the posting.

Happy coding.

B

Comment: Thanks Brian, will come back after around 15 mins as will make the changes you wrote and test it out so it sinks in :)